# Error while deploying topology on storm cluster

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am trying to deploy a simple word count topology on storm clustre.I am using kafka as the input(kafka Spout).This is the error i am getting

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:39) at kafka.utils.Logging$class.logger(Logging.scala:24) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.logger$lzycompute(SimpleConsumer.scala:30) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.logger(SimpleConsumer.scala:30) at kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:67) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.info(SimpleConsumer.scala:30) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:74) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:127) at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:77) at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:67) at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.(PartitionManager.java:83) at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:135) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4654$fn__4669$fn__4698.invoke(executor.clj:565) at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__458.invoke(util.clj:463) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by adding log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar in my storm library.

Answer (score 1):

I am using

- storm 0.9.6
- kafka 0.9.0

With storm 0.9.6, it uses slf4j. So you need to exclude that from your kafka reference and include the log4j. Following is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <!--<exclusion>-->
            <!--<groupId>log4j</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>-->
        <!--</exclusion>-->
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```